# How to add a <script> tag to a Google Code wiki?

Tags: wiki, google-code

Admittedly, this is a tad off topic, but this seems like the best place to find people who might know the answer to this question.

I wish to add a twitter widget to my google code project home page. However, it does not appear that google's wiki markup language allows  objects.  When I try to add one, the page just displays the code instead of the widget.

Is there a way to add a  tag to a google code wiki page?

Answer (score 0):

Use a gadget -- a quick search for "twitter gadget" shows that such a thing exists.

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiSyntax explains how embed gadgets. Embedding arbitrary scripts would be a security hazard.

Comment: That seems like a solution with potential, but I can't seem to find a gadget that behaves remotely like the twitter search widget here: http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search  Most are focused on letting you update your status and read your activity stream.

Comment: Are you trying to embed a particular user's feed or a set of search terms? For the former, use the RSS feed provided by twitter. For the latter, if a gadget doesn't already exist, then making one shouldn't actually be that hard. http://wave-samples-gallery.appspot.com/about_app?app_id=89003 is a good place to start hacking.